# Data in Atom Form

Tags: string-manipulation, output-formatting

I am loading a dataset into Mathematica and the format is always recognized as an Atom String:

```
DS[All, 4]
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPX6d.png]

```
AtomQ[DS[All, 4]]
(* True *)
```

In this format I cannot analyze the data. Unfortunately, I cannot modify the data before I load it into Mathematica.

Any help is welcome.

I tried ToString (horrible outcome):

```
In[111]:= ToString[DS[All, 4]]

Out[111]= "Dataset[{23,8, 24,9, 25,7, 23,8, 23,4, 23,8, 25,9, 24,4, \
24,9, 25,4, 25,3, 26,1, 25,5, 24,0, 23,9, 26,2, 24,6, 26,6, 26,4, \
26,2}, TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[String], 20], <|Origin -> \
HoldComplete[Query[All, 4][Dataset`DatasetHandle[37310558245194]]], \
ID -> 52209799798783|>]"
```

and Replace

```
DS[All, 4] /. "," -> "."
```

but both did not work.

Comment: `Dataset` objects are always atoms, so this part is not the issue. Unless you have more specific information (e.g. part of the file you're trying to import & the code you're using to do so), it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: So it is not possible to modify the data (in Atom form) once it it designated as a dataset?

Comment: you can modify them. Take a look at the (quite extensive) documentation of `Dataset`. If you tell us in more detail what you're after, we can point you in a more specific direction

Comment: I would like to have the variable in a numerical format. Right now Mathematica cannot work with this format. All simple applications (e.g., Mean or Plot) do not work.

Comment: Can you show how you import the data? While it's possible to fix them afterwards, it might be significantly cleaner and faster to import it properly in the first place

Comment: @PhilippeDufour - anytime you have something in the form of a `Dataset`, you can use `Normal` to convert it to a useful form.  What do you see when you evaluate `Normal[DS]`?

Comment: You might need to convert strings to expressions. e.g. `ToExpression["123"] // Head`.

Comment: This seems to reproduce the dataset (but it looks like it should have been ***imported*** with the proper number conversion): ``ds = Dataset[{"23,8", "24,9", "25,7", "23,8", "23,4", "23,8", "25,9", 
   "24,4", "24,9", "25,4", "25,3", "26,1", "25,5", "24,0", "23,9", 
   "26,2", "24,6", "26,6", "26,4", "26,2"}, 
  TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[String], 20], <|
   Origin -> HoldComplete[
     Query[All, 4][Dataset`DatasetHandle[37310558245194]]], 
   ID -> 52209799798783|>]``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ds = Dataset[{"23,8", "24,9", "25,7", "23,8", "23,4", "23,8", "25,9", 
   "24,4", "24,9", "25,4", "25,3", "26,1", "25,5", "24,0", "23,9", 
   "26,2", "24,6", "26,6", "26,4", "26,2"}, 
  TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[String], 20], <|
   Origin -> HoldComplete[
     Query[All, 4][Dataset`DatasetHandle[37310558245194]]], 
   ID -> 52209799798783|>];

ds2 = ds[Interpreter["Number", NumberPoint -> ","]]
```

[image]

```
Total[ds2]
(*  500.8  *)

Mean[ds2]
(*  25.04  *)
```

Probably the dataset could have been imported as a list of numbers instead of strings to begin with, but if not, then you can convert as above.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! That worked.

Comment: @PhilippeDufour You're welcome.